# Which upgrade items have synergies?

Tags: skyforce-unite

While upgrading a H2V12 Rocket and attempting to reduce its weight footprint, I accidentally stumbled on a combination of **Fairy Shoes** and **Ectoplasm** which slightly increased the effectiveness of both items. Unfortunately I have not yet found any others, as upgrading parts can get expensive.

Which leads me to my question; *Which items will boost each other when combined in the same part?*

Answer (score 2):

Here is my list

- Fairy Hat + Shoes + Birdwing
- Ectoplasm + Stick fruid
- Ember + Oil + Cloth + Acohol
- Any xxx(munim) + Rare metal
- Steel + Spiral crew
  -> up top is what I found, it boost point in all parts have enough slot
- any deck + Wind stone + xxx(munim) 2 pcs or above , you will get a passive skills agains Wind element

Answer (score 0):

Only one ive found was fairy shoes and bird feather. Did the same thing. Slight boost to both and some increased weight reduction I believe. I wish there was a list of items, and outcomes of adding them to each type of part.